# Django Admin Login 403 Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)

Tags: django, django-admin, django-csrf

I am trying to login admin panel but I am getting 403 Forbidden error.  Last week, there was not error. I did not change anything. I almost tried all solution of same problems in StackOverFlow. Please help me! Thanks for reading. I apologize for my poor English.

**System**:

```
Ubuntu 16.04
Python 3.5
Django 2.0
Gunicorn
Nginx
iRedMail
```

**django debug.log**

```
    Exception while resolving variable 'is_popup' in template 'admin/login.html'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/xxx/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 829, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/xxx/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 83, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'is_popup'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/xxx/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 835, in _resolve_lookup
    if isinstance(current, BaseContext) and getattr(type(current), bit):
AttributeError: type object 'RequestContext' has no attribute 'is_popup'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/xxx/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 843, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[int(bit)]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'is_popup'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/xxx/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 850, in _resolve_lookup
    (bit, current))  # missing attribute
django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [is_popup] in [{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, {'base_url': 'domain.com', 'DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS': {'DEBUG': 10, 'SUCCESS': 25, 'WARNING': 30, 'ERROR': 40, 'INFO': 20}, 'perms': <django.contrib.auth.context_processors.PermWrapper object at 0x7f3ea494a128>, 'messages': <django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage object at 0x7f3ea4977240>, 'request': <WSGIRequest: GET '/admin/login/?next=/admin/'>, 'user': <SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x7f3ea4977278>>, 'csrf_token': <SimpleLazyObject: <function csrf.<locals>._get_val at 0x7f3ea49a2048>>, 'categories': <QuerySet [<Category: ASD>, <Category: ASD>, <Category: ASD>, <Category: ASD>, <Category: ASD>]>}, {}, {'site_url': '/', 'next': '/admin/', 'title': 'Oturum aç', 'view': <django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView object at 0x7f3ea4977320>, 'username': '', 'LANGUAGE_BIDI': False, 'site': <django.contrib.sites.requests.RequestSite object at 0x7f3ea4977630>, 'site_name': 'www.domain.com', 'LANGUAGE_CODE': 'TR', 'form': <AdminAuthenticationForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(username;password)>, 'available_apps': [], 'site_title': '', 'has_permission': False, 'app_path': '/admin/login/?next=/admin/', 'site_header': ''}]
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /admin/login/
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/00-default.conf**

```
#
# Note: This file must be loaded before other virtual host config files,
#
# HTTP
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.com;

     location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
     location /static/ {
     root /home/xxx/xxx;
     expires 1M;
     access_log off;
     add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

location /media/ {
     root /home/xxx/xxx;
     expires 1M;
     access_log off;
     add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
location / {
     include proxy_params;
     proxy_pass http://unix:/home/xxx/xxx/domain.sock;
     add_header X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
     add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
     add_header 'Referrer-Policy' 'no-referrer';
     add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';";
     add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
}

}
server {
     # Listen on ipv4
     listen 443;

     # Listen on ipv6.
     # Note: this setting listens on both ipv4 and ipv6 with Nginx release
     #       shipped in some Linux/BSD distributions.
     #listen [::]:80;
     server_name https://mail.domain.com;
}
```

Comment: You need to pass `is_popup ` in template context

Comment: Your error is at `is_popup`

Comment: @ArtemBernatskyi how can i do?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context if you use CBV

Comment: Show code where you are populating `is_popup ` variable

Comment: @ArtemBernatskyi I think my problem is not related to 'is_popup' . I have a form at my index page for appointments. If i have remove csrf middleware in settings.py, this form works! but admin login form not work. I've looked in Developer Console in Mozilla. When i post form, 'Set-Cookie: csrftoken=......' is unable to set in Response Header section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved**
Modified the file settings.py which had the following line:

```
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
```

Comment: Hello! Did you find any other solution to this fault on login to admin. This solves the fault itself, but it makes admin part of the site vulnerable to attacks as I understand.

Comment: No, this solved my problem. I did not try any other solution.

Comment: Hello! I found this solution, which allows leave csrf to be switched on. It suites for latest Django. It's not my solution. Originally It was taken from Django docs, but I don't have reference to the docs where is it. And I also saw some post with this kind of solution... In settings.py: SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=True
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True

Answer (score 1):

I feel like to add some more information here... Switching off csrf is not recommended in documentation...

I hope it might help to somebody...

You can also include in settings into the context_processors the following:
'django.template.context_processors.csrf',

This line should automatically include csrf token into templates... so it should eliminate csrf cookie not set fault...

Honestly, I set this line into my settings, but because I used solution in the above settings, and it solved my 'cookie not set' thing, I cannot confirm 100% it helps with this fault... But it is one more way to fight problems with csrf token...